# содержание блока над разными элементами

Tags: html, прокрутка

Есть страница:

```html
<div style="position:fixed; right:10px; top:10px;"><img></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
<div class="class3"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class4"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке, как только блок окажется над элементом с классом class1, в нем менялось содержание, а именно - картинка? Над блоками с другим классом - картинка не менялась.

Comment: javascript в помощь

Comment: тут ведь задают вопросы а не работу, начни хотя бы сам писать скрипт на js